# Deleting record from MongoDB using Angular

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

I'm trying to delete a record from MongoDB by using Angular on the FrontEnd, but somehow I can't get it to work.

This is my Delete request in Express:

```
router.get('/ideas/:id', function(req, res){
  ideas_data.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

And this is the http function in Angular:

```
$scope.deleteRec = function(id){
    $http.delete('/ideas/:id', {_id : id})
      .then(function successCallback(response) { 
        console.log(response);
    });
  };
```

And this is the function call on click in HTML

```
<a href="/{{title}}/{{x._id}}" ng-click="deleteRec(x._id)">
  <div class="icon cross">
     <img src="/images/icons/cross.svg"/>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you get any console error?

Comment: Yes, a "DELETE http://123.456.789/ideas/:id 404 not found" error and a very long "Possibly unhandled rejection" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling delete method from angular and server you have written get.

```
router.delete('/ideas/:id', function (req, res) {
    ideas_data.remove({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx, this was partly the answer to the problem. I had to change res.redirect into res.sendStatus(200). That did the trick for the errors in the console